# Is it possible to pause code until promise is resolved?

Tags: reactjs, promise, lifecycle

My code contains the event listener below. I am trying to pause my code until the promise (window.ethereum.enable()) in the event listener is resolved. How should I go about doing this?

```
window.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        this.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        try {
          await window.ethereum.enable();
          alert("if:" + this.web3)
          return this.web3;
        } catch(err){}
      }
      else if (window.web3) {
        this.web3 = window.web3;
        return this.web3;
      }
      else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/PROJECT-ID');
        this.web3 = new Web3(provider);
        return this.web3;
      }

      this.web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => { this.state.account = accounts[0]});
    })
```

Comment: The `await` you have in the code does just that, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is currently not possible in javascript (unless you want to hack something with web workers, but this is not what you want here). Even `await` is only syntactical sugar to make the code look procedural, but it uses promises under the hood. The reason is that javascript runs a single thread only, so there is no "other" thread that would need to wait.

What you may want to do is to first kick of some kind of "loading indicator" to show the user that stuff is loading. Then call your async stuff and give it a callback (e.g. the `resolve` function of the promise) to set your application in the next state (i.e. remove the loading indicator and do what ever is the follow up). Of course, you can use the `await` syntax to make it look and even sound like "waiting", but keep in mind, that in reality there is only a single thread running.